# Rudin 1.22: the "converse" direction

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

I'm trying to understand the section in Rudin on decimal expansions. I've written it up below.

> Let $x > 0$. Let $n_0$ be the largest integer such that $n_0 \leq x$. (Note that the existence of $n_0$ depends on the archimedean property of $\mathbb{R}$.) Having chosen $n_0,n_1, \ldots, n_{k-1}$, let $n_k$ be the largest integer such that
> $$
> n_0 + \frac{n_1}{10} + \cdots + \frac{n_k}{10^k} \leq x. \hspace{4mm} (5)
> $$
> Then $x = \sup E$. The decimal expansion of $x$ is
> $$
> n_0. n_1 n_2 n_3 \cdots \hspace{4mm} (6). 
> $$
> Conversely, for any infinite decimal (6) the set $E$ of numbers (5) is bounded above, and (6) is the decimal expansion of $\sup E$.

I believe I understand the "forward direction" (everything before "conversely"). I don't understand everything after "conversely." The first problem is, I don't understand what exactly this is the converse of. My understanding of what Rudin did in the first part was take a positive real number $x > 0$ and derive its decimal expansion. Is the goal to show that he can go backwards from a decimal expansion to a unique real number, in which case there is a bijective correspondence between the two? I'm not completely sure how this construction deals with real numbers with non-unique decimal expansions, unless we just agree from the start that we're not going to work with decimal expansions with infinitely many $9$'s.

Comment: Your interpretation is accurate. In the first part, derive a decimal representation from a real number. In the "converse", derive a real number from a decimal representation.

Comment: You can axiomatically disallow decimal expansions with infinitely many $9$s.

Comment: @K.Jiang Can you explain a bit more about how I can do this? I'm not completely sure I follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In natural language you're first proving that every real number has a decimal expansion then you're showing that every decimal number converges to some real number. The fact that there are non-unique representations is immaterial as they have the same supremum regardless. They're using that the sequence of partial sums is monotonic increasing and bounded which ensures the existence of the supremum by the [monotonic convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem). So the familiar example of decimals is easily understood using more abstract results.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. Is the bound (or at least the sup) of the sequence of partial sums the real number $x$ itself?

Comment: @BradG. Yes the supremum is the real number we associate with the decimal expansion. So while $0.99..$ and $1.000..$ are distinct series they have the same supremum and so represent the same real number that we normally call $1$.